# sRGB mode a necessary for monitors?

Tags: color, color-correction, color-spaces, display-calibration, monitors

I was wondering. If there's no dedicated sRGB mode on a monitor, can you still calibrate it to an sRGB color gamut for photo and video color grading? I am referring to the Cooler Master GM34CW with 95% DCI-P3 and 125% sRGB. And I am worried if I were to buy this monitor for colorwork it might mess up how my products look. Is it really a deal breaker if a monitor does not have this mode? Or will I be able to work around it by using a calibrator to calibrate to sRGB? Thank you very much to whoever can answer my question! Have a great day!

P.s. I am a newbie so I'm sorry if this seems such a basic question. I've tried searching google about it and I got more confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is… you don't really calibrate **to** something specific, unless that's your only ever input and output type. Calibrating to sRGB would mean you could never see outside that gamut - a bit of a waste with a screen that can almost achieve P3.
Let's assume you never (or rarely) need to calibrate for commercial print, which is a whole different ball-game (you can get close with a default setup but your white point would need to be different for a real print-based solution.) Let's stick to photos/videos & predominantly delivery for other computers or via web.

If, for instance, you were to use the X-Rite system with an i1 Display (they make several version of higher quality/greater cost) spectrometer, then aside from setting the software to 'Advanced mode' you pretty much leave everything to the software.
You set to advanced because you can then use the much larger swatch set that isn't available in Basic & really makes a lot of difference to the end result. Leave everything else as it is (Default) right through.
Before you start calibration, it's best to switch your display to a basic 'stupid' mode. Don't let your display try to be 'smart' at all for a calibrated display.
The calibration software will then run you through some basic on-screen settings (brightness, contrast, R,G,B balance) you access through your display's OSD to ensure a 'clean' start point.

What you end up with is an icc profile for your specific display, which is set by the calibration software to be your computer's new default profile. Your computer & software then uses this to translate **any** input to an output curve correct for your display.

Then, in Photoshop for instance, you check to make sure your display profile is in the list of potential profiles… but you never use it in Photoshop. Your computer is already handling that for you. Photoshop just needs to know it's there.
This is a very common beginner's mistake. People set their Photoshop working profile to their display profile.
*This does not work.*

You set your workflow to the "best" for your work requirements. Sensible default if you're working predominantly to web/computer is sRGB, but for any already-profiled input, *stick with that profile*.
If you work from a DSLR, then you can use its own profile right the way through. If you need to Export to sRGB, then that's the only time you do. Your input stays at your camera profile - mine, for instance is Nikon Adobe RGB 4.0 - which is "better" than sRGB (wider gamut) but not as good as P3.
Also, my displays can achieve just over 100% Adobe RGB but not P3 so this is a workflow I **can** use without ever not being able to see the colours as best as possible. If you were using something like a newer iPhone which is capable of P3 for your input photographs, then you'd stay with P3 right through… though as your display can only achieve 95% P3<sup>[1]</sup> run a couple of tests first to make sure there are no surprises when exporting to sRGB)

If you work in this wider gamut then reduce to sRGB right at the end - only at export & never change your profile in your PSD document - the difference will become as small as it possibly can be between your intent & what you see on screen after export. Personally, I have real trouble telling the difference between my output JPGs converted to sRGB at 100% quality from my PSDs still at Nikon Adobe RGB.

This, then, makes full use of your screen's capabilities and gives you the highest flexibility at output to whatever your final form must be.

<sup>[1]</sup> I did find this review of i1 calibration on your specific display which managed to squeeze full P3 out of it. YMMV - https://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/coolermaster_gm34-cw.htm#calibration

Comment: Hi it's me again! Okay first off I will apologize because I am having a hard time understanding what you just said. I've read it multiple times and there are still some things I'm confused about. Firstly, after I calibrate my screen, I will then have an ICC profile specific for my display, correct? What then do you mean by this "Your computer & software then uses this to translate any input to an output curve correct for your display."

Comment: I mean, that's the end of your involvement in what the profile does for you. Your OS will handle it from there on in. Whatever document you open, if it has a document profile (if not it will assume sRGB), your machine will correctly translate it to your screen.

Comment: Secondly, why shouldn't I set my photoshop color profile the same as my display color profile? Wouldn't that make my edits look more consistent? Is this the same for Premiere Pro? By the way, I am a photographer and videographer and I'm just concerned if I edit in a wider color gamut, will it look different when viewed in sRGB displays?

Comment: Thirdly, you said that "If you work in this wider gamut then reduce to sRGB right at the end - only at export & never change your profile in your PSD document - the difference will become as small as it possibly can be between your intent & what you see on screen after export". Do you mean that I wouldn't have to worry about editing it in a wider color gamut as long as I export it in sRGB so that the colors stay consistent? How does this apply to premiere pro?

Comment: For some reason, beginners just never get this. It doesn't work. You end up with two translations. Once you have your display correctly profiled, then just leave it alone. It may look different on another display - but you're not in control of someone else's display. All you can do is control your own. Yes. Work in wide gamut, export in consumer-friendly. one conversion right at the end.

Comment: Lastly, I've read that Tft review of the monitor, and I was head-over-heels for it but they said in verbatim "There was unfortunately no sRGB emulation mode so you were stuck with the full wide gamut all the time, which might not be ideal if you wanted to do any color critical work". That statement was the reason behind all of my questions. Is sRGB mode for displays really that necessary for color-critical work, but thanks to you, you removed my doubts and educated me on this matter. Thank you very much!

Comment: That seems an odd thing for them to say. Sure, a quick switch might be useful if you weren't running a calibrated system, but any half decent app will have soft-proofing & any already profiled image will be correctly translated to screen because you have the correct profile for your display.

Comment: That's what I figured at first! But that statement sowed doubt in my mind. But I feel more reassured and educated about my purchase. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: X-Rite has one (current) i1 colorimeter. There's no difference in the hardware between any of the i1 colorimeters other than the color of the housing. The only difference in the price levels are the license keys provided with each version that unlocks various levels of the software. The X1 Spectrophotometers are used for measuring actual surfaces of products, not screen output. You need the colorimeter for that.

Answer (score 0):

When a monitor is calibrated it is measured for its entire gamut and not the ability to match any other gamut.  Then if that monitor's gamut is at least sRGB or larger when sRGB images are displayed they may be displayed correctly (If monitor profiling is done properly and the lighting around the monitor is dim and not variable)

That monitor profile provides the ability to display sRGB files correctly, only if it is large enough to cover sRGB.